# XDocument changes tab to space

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have a xml-document that simplified looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node1 separator="    " />
```

There is a `\t` as attribute value.

When executing this code

```
var path = @"C:\test.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
doc.Save(path);
```

the attribute value changed from tab to space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node1 separator=" " />
```

Is there a way to preserve the origin value, because it is required to be a tab?

Comment: try to use `expandtab` option.

Comment: Have you tried adding `xml:space="preserve"` to `Node1`?

Comment: Both suggestions didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "XML whitespace normalization in attributes" portion of [XML:Attribute-Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006.html#AVNormalize) which is default behavior when handling XML documents.

> For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value

You should be able to use [XmlTextReader.Normalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmltextreader.normalization%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1fs4xt2c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). XmlDocument can load from reader [XmlDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ta6tz4.aspx).

```
var path = @"C:\test.xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
doc.Load(reader);
var s = doc.SelectSingleNode("*/@*").InnerText;
Console.WriteLine("|{0}|, {1}", (int)s[0], s.Length); // prints 9 - ASCII code of tab
doc.Save(path);
```